# Error using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I had CUDA 7.5 installed before and have just removed it and installed CUDA 8.0. After doing that, cmake has started giving error on any kind of compilation , giving these errors:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find CUDA: Found unsuitable version "8.0", but required is exact
  version "7.5" (found /usr/local/cuda-8.0)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:386 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:949 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake:48 (find_package)
  /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake:291 (find_host_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/cortana/Desktop/app/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/cortana/Desktop/app/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

This error came up on compiling some opencv code. Considering that on not using cmake, the code compiles alright, opencv isn't broken. But cmake is showing such behaviour. Also, I am not even using cuda, so I dont know how its coming up. How can I remove this problem?

Edit: 
Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT (app)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED )

set( SRC
    code.cpp
)


INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include )
link_directories( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
add_executable( {PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC} )

target_link_libraries( {PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue. Turns out that the v3.1 of opencv has just been updated to support CUDA 8.0. I rebuilt the latest source code and installed it which made the code start working again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the code you are compiling is not using CUDA, just go to the file named `CMakeLists.txt` and delete anything related to CUDA like `findPackage cuda` or something similar. However, I doubt that someone will put this in `CMakeLists.txt` without the need of it.

---

**After OP's edit:**

it seems that the OpenCV version is configured with CUDA. If you want to get rid of it. use something similar to:

```
find_package(OpenCV COMPONENTS opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc REQUIRED)
```

Ofcourse, add any other module you want.

Note: not tested.